# Domain name in mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The task is to get referer domain and send it to my script by RewriteRule. My decision is

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^https?://(.*)/" myref=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php?referer=%{ENV:myref}
```

It works right but I wonder if there are any ways to do it (perhaps with RewriteCond)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite has a variable named `%{HTTP_REFERER}`. It contains what you expect. You can use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script\.php$
RewriteRule ^ script.php?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for more information.